# Assign TAB in markdown mode

Tags: key-bindings, evil, markdown, markdown-mode

Running emacs 25.2.2, general, evil and markdown-mode installed from MELPA.

The problem is when I hit `TAB` on a heading in a markdown file, it does not cycle visibility of content.

`C-h k TAB` shows it is assigned to `evil-jump-forward`.

So, in my `init.el`, I added:

```
(general-def 'markdown-mode-map
  "TAB" 'markdown-cycle)
```

But still `TAB` is assigned to `evil-jump-forward`.

How do I assign `TAB` to `markdown-cycle` in `markdown-mode`?

Moreover, can I assign it such that only when the cursor is on a heading, it is assigned to `markdown-cycle` but at other locations, it is assigned to `evil-jump-forward`?

Comment: This doesn't help with your additional question and no idea whether this solves it, but you should remove the `'` before `markdown-mode-map` when using `general-def`

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this as well. The reason your attempt isn't working, is because of `evil` and the way it binds keys to a higher level keymap (as far as I understand the matter).

Anyways, you can bind directly to the corresponding `evil` state you want to use the key in.

The following should do the trick:

```
(evil-define-key 'normal markdown-mode-map
       (kbd "<tab>") 'markdown-cycle)
```

(You might need to hit `tab` twice if there are no subheadings.)

The package `evil-markdown` provides much more complete integration with `evil`. Not on MELPA, unfortunately, so you'll have to install it manually. Check it out on https://github.com/Somelauw/evil-markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Supporting the [previous answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/44449/29032), I think `<tab>` needs to be replaced with `TAB`. For me, snippet in above answer didn't work but the following snippet worked:

```lisp
(evil-define-key 'normal markdown-mode-map
  (kbd "TAB") 'markdown-cycle)
```

All the change is that I have used `TAB` instead of `<tab>`.